# How to create mongodb collections using 'node-mongodb-native' with validators as per defined mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jsonschema, node-mongodb-native

I want to create empty collections with validators that work same when we want to insert or update using mongoose!
In-short, validations at collection-level!

I've tried creating mongodb schema ($jsonSchema) using [mongoose-schema-jsonschema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-schema-jsonschema), but it throws error `Unknown $jsonSchema keyword: x-ref`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-schema-jsonschema')(mongoose);
const contact = require('./schemas/contact');

contact.jsonSchema('name mobile email message token is_active status status_comment version');
const contact_schema = contact.jsonSchema('', 'country_id state_id suburb_id subject_id created_by modified_by');

let connection;
const get_mongodb_resource = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('get_mongodb_resource started ');

    const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true };
    await mongoose.connect(process.env,MONGODB_URI, options);
    mongoose.set('debug', true);
    console.info('get_mongodb_resource connected');
    connection = mongoose.connection;
    connection.db.createCollection('contact_schema', { validator: { $jsonSchema: contact_schema } });
    return mongoose.connection;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('connection to mongodb failed');
    console.log(error, error.stack);
    return new Error(error);
  }
};
```

How can I do this, either **with node-mongodb-native or with mongoose**?

Comment: The library you're using creates a schema with `x-ref`, but this is not a JSON Schema keyword, nor does it seem to appear in the list of supported keywords for mongodb, and is rejected by the validator. The library doesn't document where this comes from.

Comment: I know that, but how can I acheive creating collections with validations?

Comment: I don’t think you can. Have a look at this article... “The JSON Schema firstly determines how the data is stored. It is designed to check a JSON document, not a MongoDB collection, so we need to convert a ‘collection’ of documents into an array of documents.” - https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/json-schema-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, we can conclude that we need mongoose for schema validations and we cannot create empty collections with only validations defined using mongoose?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about mongodb except it uses JOSN Schema for validation. Hopefully someone else can help with your specific question.